# Asynchronous method in while loop with Graph API paged

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-node-sdk

I'm using [facebook node sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/facebook-node-sdk) for node.js to get information from a facebook user such as their feed and friends, which is working fine.

However I'm having an issue where the returned data is paged - I need to build something in recursive mode. Let me explain:

```
FB.api('/me/feed?limit=5000', {
    access_token: token
}, function(response) {
  // response is an object that could have as response.paging.next attribute
});
```

Limit isn't working here, because it returns a max of 245 and returns **paging** object indicating the next page of results.

Because the next call depends of the result of the previous async call, I tried to do something like this:

```
// first call before
var hasNext = response.paging.next ? true : false;
while (hasNext){
    FB.api('/me/feed', {
        access_token: token
    }, function(response_paged) {
       response.data.concat(response_paged.data);
       // If do not have a next page to break the loop
       if (!response_paged.paging.next) hasNext = false;
    });
}
```

*The way the next token was obtained is not important for now*

The point is I'm trying to do async calls in recursive mode, but its not working, this way I'm getting an infinite loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My idea of solving this with async/await:

```
async function getFeed(token) {
    let feedItems = [],
        hasNext = true,
        apiCall = '/me/feed';

    while (hasNext) {
        await new Promise(resolve => {
            FB.api(apiCall, {access_token: token}, (response) => {
                feedItems.concat(response.data);
                if (!response.paging.next) {
                    hasNext = false;
                } else {
                    apiCall = response.paging.next;
                }
                resolve();
            });
        });
    }
    return feedItems;
}

getFeed().then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Be aware that you need Node.js 7.9.0+ for this: http://node.green/

For older versions, install this: https://github.com/yortus/asyncawait

You can also use a recursive function, but the smooth/modern way would be async/await.

Comment: Doesn't works @luschn. I tried also with a simple loop a counter and when  is it to set 30 for example to stop, but still blocked in loop.

Comment: you can´t use a simple loop, you have to wait for each callback. either with a recursive function or async/await. what do you mean by "doesn´t work"? did you debug my code? i can test it later, but a more detailed explanation would be helpful if it does not work. any errors?

Comment: No errors, the code runs, but it's as `await` block do not wait the response of API, I think I'm doing something wrong..

Comment: what node.js version are you using?

Comment: Version 7.9 nodejs

Comment: and the function is defined as "async"?

Comment: ah, now i get it. sorry, my mistake. FB.api does not return a promise. i will fix the code.

Comment: Ohh, that's worked! Thanks! Only curiosity..this works with node.js 7.6?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using:

```
feedItems.concat(response.data);
```

I have made: (if is the case on response.data has the data)

```
for(var i in response.data){
   feedItems.push(response.data[i]);
}
```

Comment: Although this isn't the issue of the questions, thank you for the good catch when concating.

Answer (score 0):

As of today (12/10/21) response.data is of type Object. The below would now be appropriate for saving response data.

```js
for (let d of response.data) {
  feedItems.push(d)
}
```