# Facebook Workplace Graph API, return unlimited

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-workplace

How do I return a set of results that is unlimited in size from Facebook Workplace's Graph API? It is limited by default to 25, but I can manually increase this by introducing the limit parameter.

`https://graph.facebook.com/<company_id>/members?limit=500`

I can obviously use a limit value way in excess of anything I'll need, but that just seems messy. Is there a way to prevent Facebook from limiting the number of results returned?

Comment: no, there is no unlimited option. you should use paging.

Comment: Thanks @luschn, if you phrase that as an answer with an example of how to implement paging then I'll mark it as the solution

Comment: @Sinfieldd: I am also developing a workplace api using python to extract the data. I have an access token but do not have a Community ID. I am not sure on how to get it from workplace? Would be great if you could please share some info. about it

Comment: The community ID is available in the admin section of Workplace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option to get unlimited results, you can use paging to get all of them - with a recursive function, for example.

Paging: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#paging

If you are using Node.js on your server, you can also use async/await, like in this example: [Asynchronous method in while loop with Graph API paged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43564239/asynchronous-method-in-while-loop-with-graph-api-paged/43564379#43564379)