# How to do pagination using Node JS for Facebook Graph API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook-graph-api, while-loop, fb-graph

I want to extract all the posts of a specific Facebook Page.
I've already written this code in Python but I don't know how to do that in Node.js.

With this code, I only extract the first page of Graph API and the loop stops.
Where am I wrong in this piece of code?
I think I got confused with Python :)

I would be appreciated for your help.

```
var graph = require('fbgraph');

var accessToken = "MyAccessToken"
graph.setAccessToken(accessToken);

graph.setVersion("2.11");

var options = {
    timeout:  3000,
    pool:     { maxSockets:  Infinity },
    headers:  { connection:  "keep-alive" }
};

graph.setOptions(options)

graph.get("5550296508?fields=posts", function(err, resp) {
    var data = resp;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    while (true){
    if(data.posts.paging && data.posts.paging.next){
        graph.get(data.posts.paging.next, function(err, res) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
            var data = res
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: make sure you understand what "asynchronous" means, it is important to know in the javascript world. also, google for "async/await", it will help you.

Comment: @luschn here I found an example that you already have written: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43564239/asynchronous-method-in-while-loop-with-graph-api-paged  I wanted to ask: before your code I should assign the variable FB so: var FB = require('facebook-node-sdk'); ?

Comment: honestly...if you need to ask if you should require a package in node.js, you should go through some very basic node.js tutorials first ;)

Comment: either way, the example in that other thread should be good enough to learn how to deal with this.

Comment: @luschn [shy] :) If I assign the variable var FB = require('facebook-node-sdk');  I get this error: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 3): TypeError: FB.api is not a function

Comment: And according to the documentation if I assign the variable var FB = new Facebook({ appID: 'YOUR_APP_ID', secret: 'YOUR_APP_SECRET' });  I get this error: Callback cannot throw error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'next' of undefined

Comment: i suggest using the "fb" module instead. try that one.